# No error for lists of unequal length compared

Tags: python, pandas

Given a list of dataframes I am trying to find if I can merge similar tables.

```
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J']}

dummy_data2 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
        'Feature1': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
        'Feature2': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}

dummy_data3 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
        'Feature1': ['R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data3, columns = ['id', 'Feature1'])
```

This operation(see code below) is very well understood(No error in case 1 and length mismatch in case 2)

```
>>>df1.columns == df2.columns # CASE 1
>>>array([ True,  True,  True])

>>>df1.columns == df3.columns # CASE 2
>>>ValueError                                
   Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-107-d30deec2e5d5> in <module>
   ----> 1 df1.columns == df3.columns
   ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

But when I'm doing

```
>>>mergeRequired = False if False in df1.columns == df3.columns else True
>>>print(mergeRequired)
>>>True
```

I should get `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare` instead of `True`. Why is this not throwing any error ? How can I force the program to throw error at `mergeRequired = False if False in df1.columns == df3.columns else True` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you write this code:

```
mergeRequired = False if False in df1.columns == df3.columns else True
```

It is interpreted in the same way as this one:

```
mergeRequired = False if (False in df1.columns) == df3.columns else True
```

because the operators `in`and `==` have the same precedence in Python (see [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html)), which explains the observed behavior.

To fix your problem, you should use parentheses as follows:

```
mergeRequired = False if False in (df1.columns == df3.columns) else True
```

Comment: In that case If I split it into `condition_ = False in df1.columns` then `mergeRequired = False if condition_ == df3.columns else True` should give `True` (As it's the same as above) but it's returning `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Still curious why the result is `True`